# Git make local branch track master from second remote. Github/Overleaf

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote

I have my thesis in github and on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com).
However on my master branch on github (and locally) I have several files which are not accepted by Overleaf and I can't push them. Therefore I created another branch called "overhoja" where I removed those files and changed the .gitignore.
However, [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) does not allow to create new branches and I have to push into the master branch of the overleaf remote.

I can do this with:

```
git push -u overleaf overhoja:master
```

But my overhoja branch is somehow still tracking the origin/master.

```
git checkout overhoja
Switched to branch 'overhoja'
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
 (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I tried to do:

```
git branch --track overhoja overleaf/master
error: the requested upstream branch 'overleaf/master' does not exist
```

My config file looks like this:

```
 1 [core]
 2     repositoryformatversion = 0
 3     filemode = true
 4     bare = false
 5     logallrefupdates = true
 6 [remote "origin"]
 7     url = git@github.com:santiagocasas/PhDThesis.git
 8     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 9     pushurl=git@github.com:santiagocasas/PhDThesis.git
 10 [branch "master"]
 11         remote = origin
 12         merge = refs/heads/master
 13 [remote "github"]
 14     url = git@github.com:santiagocasas/PhDThesis.git
 15     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
 16 [remote "overleaf"]
 17     url = https://git.overleaf.com/5886143jdywnw
 18     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 19 [branch "cumuthesis"]
 20         remote = origin
 21         merge = refs/heads/cumuthesis
 22 [branch "overhoja"]
 23         remote = overleaf
```

So to summarize, I just want to be able to go to branch overhoja, and git automatically track overleaf/master and push to that.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set your local branch to follow a different upstream branch.
Try `git branch -u openleaf/master openleaf` or `git branch --set-upstream openleaf/master openleaf` (depending on your git version)